# Is there a song preview API that I can use to make games?

Tags: api

All the APIs that I am looking at that can provide previews of songs (iTunes, Spotify, Deezer, SoundCloud, last.fm, Napster, and more) provide restrictions that the audio clips for songs cannot be implemented either in entertainment applications (like games), in commercial applications, or both. Does anyone know of a song preview API that allows its users to create a game (not even commercial, but this would be nice too)?

Thanks for the help!